# xslt: XPath select elements with specific attribute value

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
<list list-type="simple" specific-use="front">
    <list-item><p>Preface <xref rid="b-9781783084944-FM-001" ref-type="sec">00</xref></p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>Series Title <xref rid="b-9781783084944-FM-003" ref-type="sec">00</xref></p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>Dedication</p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>Acknowledgments <xref rid="b-9781783084944-FM-005" ref-type="sec">00</xref></p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>Contributors <xref rid="b-9781783084944-FM-006" ref-type="sec">00</xref></p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>Glossary <xref rid="b-9781783084944-FM-008" ref-type="sec">00</xref></p></list-item>
</list>
```

I need output lik below

```
<div class="pagebreak" id="b-9781783084944-FM-002">
    <h2 class="PET"><a href="#tocb-9781783084944-FM-002">CONTENTS</a></h2>
    <div class="TocPrelims"><a href="#b-9781783084944-FM-001">Preface</a></div>
    <div class="TocPrelims"><a href="#b-9781783084944-FM-002">Series Title</a>  </div>
</div>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="list[@specific-use='front'][@list-type='simple']/list-item/p">
  <div class="TocPrelims">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:text>#toc</xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//list[@specific-use='front'][@list-type='simple']/list-item/p/xref[@rid]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </a>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Above coding of mine is not correct.. pls give suggestions.

Comment: Can you please improve the formatting of the code in your question. If you edit the question and highlight the code samples, then just click the `{}` button to format it (which puts 4 spaces before each line) to make it readable. Thank you!

Comment: @Raja Ananth, if below answer suits your requirement, then accept by tic the right mark.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this line:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//list[@specific-use='front'][@list-type='simple']/list-item/p/xref[@rid]"/>
```

Firstly, the condition will select all `xref` elements, but you only need the one for the current `p` you are positioned on. Secondly, it is selecting the `xref` element if it has an `rid` attribute, but you actually want to select the `rid` attribute. You also really want to use `xsl:value-of` here

```
<xsl:value-of select="xref/@rid"/>
```

Try this template instead:

```
<xsl:template match="list[@specific-use='front'][@list-type='simple']/list-item/p">
    <div class="TocPrelims">
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:text>#toc</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="xref/@rid"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()[1]" />
      </a>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, you can make use of Attribute Value Templates to simplify it to this:

```
<xsl:template match="list[@specific-use='front'][@list-type='simple']/list-item/p">
    <div class="TocPrelims">
      <a href="#toc{xref/@rid}">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()[1]" />
      </a>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```